# How are socket typed files(S_IFSOCK) used in Linux ext4 filesystem?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, linux-kernel, filesystems

In linux kernel, special inode for device files and FIFOs are hooked to their special `f_ops`, but sockets are left dangling. Here is a snippet from kernel 5.4 code:

```
void init_special_inode(struct inode *inode, umode_t mode, dev_t rdev)
{
    inode->i_mode = mode;
    if (S_ISCHR(mode)) {
        inode->i_fop = &def_chr_fops;
        inode->i_rdev = rdev;
    } else if (S_ISBLK(mode)) {
        inode->i_fop = &def_blk_fops;
        inode->i_rdev = rdev;
    } else if (S_ISFIFO(mode))
        inode->i_fop = &pipefifo_fops;
    else if (S_ISSOCK(mode))
        ;   /* leave it no_open_fops */
    else
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "init_special_inode: bogus i_mode (%o) for"
                  " inode %s:%lu\n", mode, inode->i_sb->s_id,
                  inode->i_ino);
}
```

In reference to FIFOs vs pipefs files, FIFOs are files in ext4 fs but hooked to ops that pipefs provides, and the above `init_special_inode()` function does the hooking. (`def_blk_fops` and `pipefifo_fops` provide the open function, which will do the rest of the setup work upon file opening)

But for socket typed files in ext4, who does the hooking (to `socket_file_ops`)?

Comment: Local sockets don't use the normal file api - you don't `open()` them, unlike fifos. That probably explains why they don't have these hooks.

Comment: @Shawn thanks, so where are the socket typed files on ext4 used at all? or is just a legacy placeholder?

Comment: See https://linux.die.net/man/7/unix - You'll see `sun_path`, which can point to any filesystem. The socket is implemented by the socket layer (`net/socket.c`). If you look at `unix_bind()` in `net/unix/af_unix.c`, you'll see the call to `unix_mknod()`.